# How can diagnose a Segmentation fault on a CentOS production server?

Tags: php, linux, segmentation-fault

We have a couple of PHP scripts that can be run from the CLI.  These both may take several hours to complete and have historical run okay (occasionally requiring memory limits to be increased).  However, on our production server, the scripts, after a relatively short period of time, will stop running with a segfault error:

```
/home/*******/bin/runlive: line 3:  9558 Segmentation fault      php 
 $HOME/********/sites/live/index.php" $*
```

(runlive - just sets up a path)
We have tried running this on a different server with the same database data and codebase and do not get the same error.
We have tried moving the production server to a new VM to discount hardware as the cause and this did not resolve the issue.
We have tried using the 'catchsegv' utility to output information about the segfault:

```
sudo /usr/bin/catchsegv runlive [script name] > catchsegv.txt
```

but this did not output anything. 
If I run these script on the same dataset, it does not always fail at the same point when processing user records which I think discounts it being a data issue.

Any ideas on how to diagnose this, much appreciated.

Comment: Is this internet-facing? Have you considered hiring penetration testers?

Comment: "We have tried moving the production server to a new VM to discount hardware as the cause" -- how do you know that the new VM didn't run on the exact same physical hardware?

Comment: Employed Russian - yeah you're right, this is a possibility, but our hosting provider performed this task, in fact, suggested it to rule out hardware failure, so I'd hope that they used new hardware - I will query this.

Comment: Stark - I'm not sure how penetration testers would help in this scenario, but in any case, we recently had pen-testers in to do testing as it is a web-facing site.  Also, these CLI scripts don't use Apache and just PHP, so again not sure what use they'd be?

Comment: The main difference when running in your production environment is that the server is being continuously attacked.  That's why I suggested pen test.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to diagnose this

There are several possibilities:

1. Bad hardware
2. Bad software

Bad software could be subdivided into:

1. Bad combination of libraries (bad version combination, powned server, etc.)
2. Bad environment (e.g. particular host name, or installation paths)

You want to use [divide and conquer](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/09/06/debugging-9-indispensable-rules/) approach to eliminate possibilities.

You've already taken the steps to eliminate hardware, but this is not yet entirely conclusive.

You'll probably want to do the following:

Build another VM (preferably in a place that you *know* is running on different physical machine), with *exactly* the same versions of all installed packages, using *trusted* source (don't just copy packages from the original machine).

Check weather the crashes still reproduce. If they do, your original server is probably not powned, and the hostname probably doesn't matter.

If the crashes don't reproduce, you've eliminated 2.1 (bad combination of versions), and now need to examine differences between the two machines with a fine comb.

Continue dividing the problem until you find the root cause.

**Or** you can take the bottom-up approach: run the `php` binary under debugger, reproduce the crash, look for upstream bug reports with similar stack trace, apply fixes for these bugs (if you find any such bugs), etc.